# Reshaping Column values of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like below without headers.

Current df:

```
Col 0    Col 1   Col 2   Col3  
2345      abcd  mobile    oneplus
4567      abbb  internet  explorer 
mozilla   2345  cccc      dddd 
eeee      bbbb  1234      hello
```

I want to have the digits value (which is `ID`) as first column (column index 0).

If in any row, the digit value shifts to `Col 1`, combine `Col 1` And `Col2` values and put it in `Col 1`, then put `Col3` value into `Col2` and then `Col0` value of next row as previous row's `Col3`.

Expected output is below:

```
Col 0     Col 1          Col 2    Col3  
2345      abcd           mobile    oneplus 
4567      abbbinternet   explorer  mozilla
2345      ccccdddd        eeee     bbbb    
1234      hello
```

Help much appreciated ! Thanks ..

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, it might be a good idea to share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using `stack`, `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
from io import StringIO

txt = StringIO("""2345      abcd  mobile    oneplus
4567      abbb  internet  explorer 
mozilla   2345  cccc      dddd 
eeee      bbbb  1234      hello""")

df = pd.read_csv(txt, header=None, sep='\s+')

df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = df.to_frame().set_index(df.str.isnumeric().cumsum())

df_out = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)[0].unstack()
df_out
```

Output:

```
      0      1         2         3        4
1  2345   abcd    mobile   oneplus      NaN
2  4567   abbb  internet  explorer  mozilla
3  2345   cccc      dddd      eeee     bbbb
4  1234  hello       NaN       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a gem. This helped me a lot.

Comment: @Swathika I am glad that worked for you.  You're welcome.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to do some cleaning before reading this data into pandas. Assuming your data is a CSV, not the prettiest code ever but this should do it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

filename = "<path to file>.csv"
new_file = "<path to where fixed csv should go>.csv"

with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    text = infile.read()

# get rid of existing new line characters
text = text.replace("\n", ",")

# put a new line before every number
out = re.sub("([0-9]+)", "\n\\1", text)

# write out
with open(new_file, "w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write(out)

# read in the fixed csv -- need to provide a number of columns
# greater than you'll need (using 50 here), and then cut the excess
df = pd.read_csv(new_file, header=None, names=range(50)).dropna(how="all", axis=1)

# jam as many columns into column1 as necessary to get just 3 after ID
df["cols_to_jam"] = df[df.columns[1:]].notnull().sum(axis=1) - 3

def jam(row):
     if row["cols_to_jam"] > 0:
         new = ""
         for col in range(1, row["cols_to_jam"] + 2):
             new += str(row[col])
     else:
         new = row[1]
     return new

idx = df[0]
col1 = df.apply(jam, axis=1)

# blank out jammed values
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["cols_to_jam"] > 0:
        for col in range(1, row["cols_to_jam"] + 2):
            df.ix[i, col] = np.nan
    else:
        df.ix[i, 1] = np.nan

del df["cols_to_jam"], df[0]

remaining_cols = df.apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna().tail(2).values), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
remaining_cols.columns = ["col2", "col3"]

# put it all together
output = idx.to_frame("id").join(col1.to_frame("col1")).join(remaining_cols)
```